# How to implement generic function of Interface in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

There is an interface CacheManager.java from shiro.

```
package org.apache.shiro.cache;

public interface CacheManager {
    <K, V> Cache<K, V> getCache(String var1) throws CacheException;
}
```

I wrote a class DefaultCacheManager.kt that implemented the CacheManager.

```
open class DefaultCacheManager : CacheManager {
    @Throws(CacheException::class)
    override fun getCache(name: String): Cache<Any, Any> {
        return InnerCache(name)
    }
} 
class InnerCache(var name: String) : Cache<Any, Any> {
//.... omitted ....
}
```

The code above would cause compilation error.

```
Conflicting overloads: 
@Throws public open fun getCache(name: String): Cache<Any, Any> defined in com.yootai.oms.permission.DefaultCacheManager, 
public abstract fun <K : Any!, V : Any!> getCache(p0: String!): Cache<K!, V!>! defined in org.apache.shiro.cache.CacheManager
```

Then, I modified my code below.

```
override fun <K : Any?, V : Any?> getCache(name: String): Cache<K, V> {
        return InnerCache(name)
}
```

But, it would give me a compilation error info.

```
Type mismatch.
Required: Cache<K,V>
Found: InnerCache
```

How can I fix the problem? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stands, you're not implementing the method from the interface: you didn't write a method that returns a cache for the *given* types, but instead you have a method that returns a cache for the `Any` type.

You need to make your own implementations generic as well:

```
open class DefaultCacheManager : CacheManager {
    @Throws(CacheException::class)
    override fun <K, V> getCache(name: String): Cache<K, V> {
        return InnerCache(name)  // creates InnerCache<K, V> thanks to type inference
    }
} 
class InnerCache<K, V>(var name: String) : Cache<K, V> {
//.... omitted ....
}
```